# No backend found in registry Android Projetct on IONIC

Tags: tensorflow, cordova, ionic-framework, tensorflow.js, ionic5

I started a new project with `tensorflow/models/posenet`. When I run I received the error:

[image: error]

Ionic:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.1 
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.7
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.7
@angular/cli                  : 10.0.7
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0
```

Cordova:

```
Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)
```

Utility:

```
cordova-res                          : 0.15.1
native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.8
```

What I tried:

```
const net = await posenet.load({
   architecture: "MobileNetV1",
   outputStride: 16,
   inputResolution: {width: 360, height: 640},
   multiplier: 0.75
});

this.Pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement);
net.dispose();
return this.Pose;
```